# How to get started with CentOS?

Tags: centos

I've been working with Debian GNU/Linux for a long time and am very proficient with it.

However for a new project I've got to got familiar with CentOS ASAP.

So my Question is: **How do I get started** (from a SysAdmin POV) **with CentOS ASAP**?

Please remember that I'm an experienced SysAdmin, I just have no experience with RPM based Distributions in general and especially CentOS and looking for good resources to get that missing knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

There is lots of help available from the CentOS website ranging from forums to documentation. If you are an experiance Sys Admin you may simply want to browse through the documentation for the release you're using and just go through areas that are differant to what you are used to (such as RPM system).

Documentation can be found here for 5.x versions: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the site contains too little information. Maybe something else?

Comment: Set up a machine, install CentOS and dig in. Nothing else will really help. Also, no cheating! No "I'll use Debian all day and dabble in CentOS a while in the evening."

Answer (score 2):

Centos ties to be an exact copy of rhel (red-hat enterprise linux). Most of the red hat documentation would apply verbatim. Centos removes most of the red hat branding an propriety licensed software they cannot distribute. You probably would not notice the difference. As you will not be using the advanced cluster management and configuration and control software the red hat uses to do that.

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/

If you have a mores specific question about a particular pieces of centos post back with a new question. The red hat certification RHCSA, carries over almost completely into centos environment. That is a great way to get a hands on introduction, on how things work. http://www.redhat.com/certification/rhcsa/objectives/